# abstract class and non-nullable value type

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, producer-consumer, non-nullable

I'm trying to compile the code ([More iterator fun with the producer/consumer pattern](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2004/06/10/MoreIteratorFunWithTheProducerconsumerPattern.aspx)
) proposed by the guru 'Joe Duffy', for class producer / consumer, but this error is occurring:

(I'm using visual studio 2010 and net 4.0.3)

```
Program.cs(37,34): error CS0453: The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'
Program.cs(11,40): (Related location)
Program.cs(37,61): error CS0453: The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'
Program.cs(11,40): (Related location)
Program.cs(44,53): error CS0453: The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'
Program.cs(11,40): (Related location)
```

Is too much for my meager knowledge! Could someone suggest a solution?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ProducerConsumerClass
{
    class Program
    {
        public abstract class Producer<T>
        {
            public Producer()
            {
                worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ProductionCycle));
            }
            private Queue<T> buffer = new Queue<T>();
            public Thread worker;
            private bool done;
            public bool Done
            {
                get
                {
                    return done;
                }
            }

            public IEnumerable<T> ConsumerChannel
            {
                get
                {
                    if (done)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Production is not currently active");

                    while (!done)
                    {
                        Nullable<T> consumed = new Nullable<T>();

                        //BUG: compiler crashes when using lock(...) construct within iterator
                        Monitor.Enter(buffer);
                        if (buffer.Count == 0)
                            Monitor.Wait(buffer);
                        if (buffer.Count > 0)
                            consumed = new Nullable<T>(buffer.Dequeue());
                        Monitor.Exit(buffer);

                        if (consumed.HasValue)
                            yield return consumed.Value;
                    }

                    yield break;
                }
            }

            public void BeginProduction()
            {
                done = false;
                worker.Start();
            }

            public void EndProduction()
            {
                done = true;
                lock (buffer)
                {
                    Monitor.PulseAll(buffer);
                }
            }

            private void ProductionCycle()
            {
                while (!done)
                {
                    T t = ProduceNext();
                    lock (buffer)
                    {
                        buffer.Enqueue(t);
                        Monitor.Pulse(buffer);
                    }
                }
            }

            protected abstract T ProduceNext();

        }

        public abstract class Consumer<T>
        {
            public Consumer(Producer<T> producer)
            {
                this.producer = producer;
                worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ConsumerCycle));
            }

            private Producer<T> producer;

            public Thread worker;

            private bool done = false;

            public bool Done
            {
                get
                {
                    return done;
                }
            }

            public void BeginConsumption()
            {
                done = false;
                worker.Start();
            }

            public void EndConsumption()
            {
                done = true;
            }

            private void ConsumerCycle()
            {
                foreach (T t in producer.ConsumerChannel)
                {
                    Consume(t);
                    if (done)
                        break;
                }
            }

            protected abstract void Consume(T t);
        }

        class RandomNumberProducer : Producer<int>
        {
            public RandomNumberProducer()
                : base()
            {
                rand = new Random();
            }

            private Random rand;

            protected override int ProduceNext()
            {
                return rand.Next();
            }
        }

        class RandomNumberConsumer : Consumer<int>
        {
            public RandomNumberConsumer(RandomNumberProducer p)
                : base(p)
            {
            }

            private static int counter = 0;

            private int id = ++counter;

            protected override void Consume(int t)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("#{0}: consumed {1}", id, t);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RandomNumberProducer p = new RandomNumberProducer();

            RandomNumberConsumer c1 = new RandomNumberConsumer(p);
            RandomNumberConsumer c2 = new RandomNumberConsumer(p);
            RandomNumberConsumer c3 = new RandomNumberConsumer(p);

            p.BeginProduction();

            c1.BeginConsumption();
            c2.BeginConsumption();
            c3.BeginConsumption();

            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            c3.EndConsumption();
            c2.EndConsumption();
            c1.EndConsumption();

            p.EndProduction();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon Skeet FTW: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230657/help-with-c-sharp-generics-error-the-type-t-must-be-a-non-nullable-value-ty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to constrain `T`:

```
public abstract class Producer<T> where T : struct
public abstract class Consumer<T> where T : struct
```

Comment: @lsalamon Also, instead of saying `Nullable<T> consumed = new Nullable<T>();` it is easier to say (and read) `T? consumed = null;`. Similarly, instead of `consumed = new Nullable<T>(buffer.Dequeue());` just say `consumed = buffer.Dequeue();`.