# Understanding C# generics and Nullable value type. Return null or nullable

Tags: c#, generics, mono, null, nullable

Suppose I have the following class:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    public T Find()
    {
        //return T if found otherwise null or Nullable<T>
    }
}
```

Somewhere I'd like to specialize my class using `T` with a `class`, other times with a `struct`.
I'm facing this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230657/help-with-c-sharp-generics-error-the-type-t-must-be-a-non-nullable-value-ty): I can't return a `Nullable<T>` if `T` type isn't restricted to be a `struct`.

I would like to provide an implementation of my `Find` method that works if `T` is specialized with both a `class` or a `struct`.
In case `Find` fails , I'd like to return `null` if `T` is a class otherwise `Nullable<T>`.

Is that possible without using reflection? If yes how?

Comment: You cannot return T or Nullable<T> if the return type is T.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can return `default(T)`.

For a class, this will be `null`.  For any `Nullable<T>`, this will be a `Nullable<T>` without a value (effectively `null`).

That being said, if you use this with a `struct` and not a `Nullable<T>` as the type, `default(T)` will be the default value of the struct.

---

If you want to make this work uniformly for any class or struct, you would likely need to return two values - you could use the framework as inspiration here, and have a TryXXX method, ie:

```
public bool TryFind(out T)
```

You could then use `default(T)` when the value isn't found, and return false.  This avoids the need for nullable types.  You could also write this returning a `Tuple<bool, T>` or similar, if you wanted to avoid the out parameter, ie:

```
public Tuple<bool, T> Find()
```

A final option, potentially, would be to make your class non-generic, then use a pair of generic methods:

```
class YourClass // Non generic
{
    public T FindReference<T>() where T : class
    {
         // ...
        return null;
    }

    public Nullable<T> FindValue<T>() where T : struct
    {
         // ...
         return default(T);
    }
}
```

Note that you need distinct names, since you can't have an overloaded method purely based on the return type.

Comment: Technically, `default(T)` will not return a `Nullable<int>` when `int` is supplied as the generic argument as the OP wants, but this definitely gets you most of the way there. Truly, the only way to get exactly what the OP wants would be to provide two generic implementations, one for value types, and one for reference types.

Comment: @Tejs. so if I need to specialize T with number type, am I forced to used the out parameter to achieve a generic solution? What does default return if T is an int?

Comment: @Tejs Yes - that's what I was trying to say in the last sentence - `default(T)` will provide a `Nullable<int>` if you use `Nullable<int>` as the generic type, thoguh.

Comment: @Heisenbug If `T` is an `int`, `default(T)` returns 0.

Comment: @Heisenbug I was (trying to) suggest you use `Nullable<int>` as your `T`, not `int` for `T`.  There is no way to return "null" for `T` without a constraint, either to class, or to struct and return `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I think I'll use out parameter solution then. Is that a common pattern using out parameter in C# for this operation?

Comment: Basically, making a method like so `public Nullable<T> FindValue<T>() where T : struct` and `public T FindReference<T>() where T : class` would let you do the operation you need to return the right type.

Comment: @Heisenbug Yes.  I edited to show. Though it's typically done as `TryFind` (TryXXX) in the framework, ie: `Int32.TryParse`, etc.

Comment: @Tejs You couldn't have that in a generic class using `T`, though - so he *might* have to rework the class logic (depends on the implementation)

Comment: Yeah, I would suggest moving the generic argument to the method instead of class, if feasible. I try to avoid using `out` on my parameters, because it makes testing more difficult, and because it looks ugly to me =D

Comment: @Tejs I just wrote that in as another option - though there are issues with that approach, as well.

Comment: @Tejs I also wrote in a tuple-based approach (which works if you want to avoid `out` parameters)

Comment: @Tejs: I don't think I'll refactor my class. I need generic parameter at the class level (GenericClass is actually a bit more complicated, it's a graph) and I don't want to use different name for methods becuase this would put too much logic on the client class. Btw, mine was just curiosity. I want to understand the subject. My T probably will never be an int, and I can go using the default approach. Thanks a lot to both of you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following solution:

```
public Boolean Find(out T result)
{
    // Pseudo code
    if (FindItem == true)
    {
        result = ItemFound;
        return true;
    }
    result = default(T);
    return false;
}
```

Why? Because `Nullable<T>` only accepts a struct and the method above supports both, classes and structs.

Comment: +1, and this idiom is usually named `TryXXXX`, so `TryGetValue` or `TryFind` would be appropriate.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Yes, you are correct. But i stayed to the name which Heisenburg used.

Answer (score 0):

As Reed said you could return `default(T)`.

In my opinion this has one big disadvantage: If your method states that `default(T)` is returned if the item was not found, you lose the ability to return the default values for value types (e.g. returning `0` for `Find<int>` might generally be a perfectly valid return value).

I would rather go for something like this

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    public Option<T> Find()
    {
        //return Option.Some(item) if found otherwise Option.None<T>()
    }
}

public static class Option
{
    public static Option<T> None<T>()
    {
        return new Option<T>(default(T), false);
    }

    public static Option<T> Some<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Option<T>(value, true);
    }
}

public sealed class Option<T>
{
    private readonly T m_Value;
    private readonly bool m_HasValue;

    public void Option(T value, bool hasValue)
    {
        m_Value = value;
        m_HasValue = hasValue;
    }

    public bool HasValue 
    {
        get { return m_HasValue; }
    }        

    public T Value 
    {
        get { return m_Value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is effectively writing a new form of `Nullable<T>` that isn't constrained to structs - now, if C# had pattern matching, this would be the way to go ;)